# Django permission belongs to group, but user on that group has no group's permission

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-guardian

I decided to not use `django-guardian` because If my customer delete/create `Group` I have to add more overhead on my `ModelManager` to transfer the existing permissions to new group. Therefore let the instances got filtered by `filter_queryset` through Django REST is fine for my case.

**FailedTestCase:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from poinkbackend.apps.companies.models import Company
from poinkbackend.apps.roles.models import Role
from poinkbackend.apps.userroles.models import UserRole
from poinkbackend.apps.commons.tests import companies, userprofiles, branches

def test_support_view_userprofile(companies, userprofiles):
    company = Company.objects.get(name='Singh')
    support = Role.objects.add_support('firstsupport', company)
    user = User.objects.get(username='notty')
    UserRole.objects.create(user=user, role=support)
    user.refresh_from_db()
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    assert True is user.has_perm('view_userprofile')
```

> ```
> -> assert True is user.has_perm('view_userprofile')
> (Pdb) user.groups.first()
> <Group: firstsupport-Singh>
> (Pdb) g1 = user.groups.first()
> (Pdb) g1.permissions.all()
> <QuerySet [<Permission: userprofiles | user profile | View UserProfile>]>
> (Pdb) user.has_perm('view_userprofile')
> False
> ```

**Question:**
Where am I wrong?

**Update 16 Nov 2017 10:30 GMT+7 Add 4th url**
**Gists:**
Company : https://gist.github.com/elcolie/684ba34391d0a94df7ca98855cea765b
Role : https://gist.github.com/elcolie/64a3a3daf22240b2072e113eb10164e2
UserRole: https://gist.github.com/elcolie/d28e7fcf54334a9f13df5fff1b7d9fe0
BusinessPermisson: https://gist.github.com/elcolie/bbeb00f41db0c7884cee34c6bccaf5f9

**References:**
[Django user has_perm returning false even though group has permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106704/django-user-has-perm-returning-false-even-though-group-has-permission)
[Django user not getting the assigned group's permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757901/django-user-not-getting-the-assigned-groups-permissions)
[django group permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474235/django-group-permission)

Comment: Sorry. My bad I just updated the debugging lines in the `FailedTestCase` gist.

Comment: Ohno my bad. `user.has_perm('userprofiles.view_userprofile')`. I forgot the `app_label`.

Comment: I strongly suggest to correct the examples. They are difficult to trace. What is the ``add_support`` method? Where is her code? Why pdb? Why do not you use console mode to prevent unnecessary jumps after the example? Where is the model (what is ``Company``, ``Role``, ``UserRole``?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I found the root cause of the error. I have updated my question according to @Adam Dobrawy comment.

The problem is I mixed up the command of guardian. `django-guardign` syntax can use without `app_label` in front of it. In my case it is `userprofiles`

I have to replace the line `user.has_perm('view_userprofile')` with `user.has_perm('userprofiles.view_userprofile')`

Again. Thank you very much Adam for your time and effort reading my question.